# Laravel - Relacionamento ManyToMany colunas extra

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Tenho o seguinte cenário em um Banco de dados:

Tabelas:

***Usuario***

- id,
- nome
- email

***Empresa***

- id
- nome

***UsuarioEmpresa***

- id_usuario
- id_empresa
- data_inicio
- data_termino

---

Nesse cenário, preciso trazer as informações das `Empresas` que o usuário faz parte e qual **data de inicio** e **fim** em cada uma delas, no `Eloquent`, fiz um relacionamento `ManyToMany`, onde no lado do `Usuario`, tenho um método `empresas()` com `belongsToMany('Empresa', 'UsuarioEmpresa')`.

Como faria para trazer esses campos do relacionamento?

Comment: A resposta do companheiro Evandro não te serviu, ela está correta para a classe `Model Usuario`?

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar o método `withPivot` ao declarar a relação e fornecer os campos adicionais, segue um exemplo.

```
 public function empresas()
 {
      return $this->belongsToMany('\App\Empresa', 
                                 'UsuarioEmpresa', 
                                 'id_usuario', 
                                 'id_empresa')->withPivot('data_inicio', 'data_termino');
 }
```

Para acessar as colunas data_inicio e data_termino em uma view você pode usar:

```
@foreach( $model->empresas as $empresa )
    {{$empresa->pivot->data_inicio}}
    {{$empresa->pivot->data_termino}}
@endforeach
```

Comment: E eu pego como os dados? Assim veio null, mas tem informacao:
<code>
@foreach ($usuario->empresas as $empresa)
{{ $empresa->data_inicio }}
</code>

Comment: Você pode acessar os os campos data_inicio e data_termino da seguinte maneira $empresa->pivot->data_inicio e $empresa->pivot->data_termino dentro do seu loop.

Comment: Alterei a resposta com a forma de acesso aos campos